# "Шаурма" во множественном числе

Tags: склонение

Одна — шаурма, три — шаурмы, а пять? Шаурм?
Как правильно сказать?

Comment: Шаурмы - пять, пива - десять...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос, хотя и известный, чтобы не сказать избитый.
Мне к Грамоте (см. у Людмилы) добавить было бы нечего, кабы не один момент. 
Тут смешивается принципиальное отсутствие (или несвободность) множественного числа и неправильность использования счетной формы для неисчислимого понятия.
Сравните: у слов вода, рыба, даже мясо форма множественного существует, но в отношении порции чего-то не используется, в любой столовой или палатке вам дадут пять (порций) *воды, мяса, рыбы,* но никак не *вод, мяс или рыб*. Аналогично - бензин, керосин, крупа и проч. (примеров точно много, лениво вспоминать).

С другой стороны пять макаронов, пельменей, - отнюдь не означает пять особей данного вида, а именно пять порций.

По всему по этому, предлагаю разделить вопросы. 
~1. У слова шаурма множественное число несвободно: шаУрмы, с родительным "шаурм". Из-за несвободноти используется редко, но вполне возможно: "не знаю я никаких шаУрм!".

~2. При использовании с числительным счетная форма (шаурм) не должна использоваться, так как само слово изначально не означает счетного понятия. Считают не штуки "шаурм", а порции. Поэтому "Пять шаурм" - неправильно.

Аналогично: халва, пахлава, фунчоза и многие прочие ближне -  и дальневосточные кушанья.

Comment: Ясно,что не должна использоваться, но в просторечии и как профессионализм у официантов часто используется метонимия - вместо "заказано 5 порций (тарелок) супа" говорят "заказали 5 супов, 5 макарон", значит, возможно и "5 шаурм".

Comment: >заказали 5 супов, 5 макарон",    
  
Макарон да, я об этом писал. 
А вот пять супов - это вряд ли. "Пять супа". Во всяком случае нигде "супов" не слушал.

Comment: *Пять пельменей* вполне может значить именно что пять *особей данного вида*, всё же они довольно крупные, поэтому их и штучно считают. А вот макароны, крупы, конечно, другое дело.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ Грамоты.ру :

Образование формы родительного падежа множественного числа слова шаурма затруднительно (хотя теоретически возможно - шаурм). Лучше сказать: пять порций шаурмы

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%F8%E0%F3%F0%EC

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказал - *пять (порций) шаурмы*. Ср. *пять (кочанов) капусты, пять (штук) паприки, пять (пакетов) сметаны* и т.д. Дело в том, что у всех этих слов нет полноценного множественного числа. В принципе, грамматически оно вполне возможно, но, видимо, "шаурм", "капуст", "паприк" и "сметан" для русских много не бывает, поэтому и используются такие конструкции.

В разговорной речи вполне допустимо опускать слова в скобках, но по строго литературной норме их всё-таки следует произносить.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от того, какой смысл мы вкладываем в слово "шаурма": если - тип блюда (как борщ, рагу и т.п.), то множественного числа не может быть в принципе; если - одна порция данного блюда, то именительный падеж множественного числа должен быть "шаУрмы" (ср. скобА - скОбы, шаурмА - шаУрмы), а родительный падеж множественного числа - "шаУрм" (ср. скОб).